# Hide some billing address's field on my account page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I am trying to hide some field I don't need to keep in my billing address at myaccount page, like: zip code and company name, I tried this code in th function.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_override_billing_fields' );
function custom_override_billing_fields( $fields ) {
  unset($fields['billing_postode']);
  return $fields;
}
```

But then the problem is when I try to checkout it tells me that you cannot  checkout:
"Unfortunately **we do not ship** . Please enter an alternative shipping address."
Even all billing fields are set?! and once i delete this code above everything woks fine!

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Please if it is not clear tell me to explain more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

So what I did is to add the following filter to the *function.php* page, for example I will hide the zip code fields, first you need to make it non required, and then hide it as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'wc_npr_filter_postcode');

function wc_npr_filter_postcode( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['billing_postcode']['type'] = 'hidden';
    return $address_fields;
}
```